# Masonry Remove Gutter and Gutterwidth

Tags: css, layout, grid, jquery-masonry, gutter

I start to make a tumblr theme for myblog and I have a problem.

My masonry code has gutter and gutterwidth. I dont want it in my codes. I research gutter option in my codes for removing but I can not remove it. It is embed code in jquery.

I want to space with padding or margin code. Not gutter / gutterwidth option... What can i do for solving it.

[**Jquery Code**](https://tumblr-vba.googlecode.com/svn/vba.jquery.masonry.min.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to (and shouldn't) edit that Jquery file. Instead, use the Masonry options. In your case:

```
"gutter": 0
```

but take a look at all the [Masonry Options](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html) to make sure you're not losing anything. Also, for vertical gutter you apply it with CSS